# Calculating area of single class in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, area, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, land-cover, image-classification

I'm doing a research about evaluation of the effect of catastrophic forest fires in Yakutia in 2021. I did some classification of three different classes: *'burned_area'*, *'vegetation'* and *'water'*. Here's my code:

```js
var postfire = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")
  .filterDate('2021-08-29', '2021-09-06')
  .filterBounds(table)
  .sort('CLOUD_COVER', false);
var mosaicpostfire = postfire.mosaic();
Map.addLayer(mosaicpostfire.clip(table), {bands: ['B7', 'B5', 'B3'], min: 0, max: 0.5}, 'После пожара');
var clippedmosaic = mosaicpostfire.clip(table);

//Merging feature collections
var newfc = burned_area.merge(vegetation).merge(water);
print(newfc);
var bands = ['B7', 'B5', 'B3'];
var training = clippedmosaic.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: newfc,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 30
});
print(training); 

//Initializing classifier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(3).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'landcover',
  inputProperties: bands
});

var classified = clippedmosaic.select(bands).classify(classifier);
Map.addLayer(classified,
{min: 0, max: 2, palette: ['9c0000', '00b32d', '0010c2']},
'Классификация');
```

I need to calculate the area of class 'burned_area'. How do I do it?

Comment: Did you try and search for some examples online? e.g. https://spatialthoughts.com/2020/06/19/calculating-area-gee/ 
Also the earth engine websites contain more than sufficient examples